# How to initialize a subclass of PFObject?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

So I'm trying to clean up my code and move all of one object's logic to it's own class.

I want to be able to do something like this:

`@interface Habit : PFObject<PFSubclassing>`
and then be able to call 
`[Habit calculateStreak]`.

How would I initialize `Habit` with an already created `PFObject` and all of its data? Something like `[Habit * running = Habit initWithThis:someObjectWithData]`? Or am I thinking of this all wrong?

Comment: To what end? You're also mixing terms for classes and instances. This question is likely better on the code review site I expect.

Comment: Sorry my explanation isn't good. Here a scenario: I have `PFObjects` with data, I want to extend their functionality to be able to do my own method such as calling the `calculateStreak` on the object.

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing is pretty easy: Just inherit from `PFObject` and adopt the `PFSubclassing` protocol:

```
@interface Habit : PFObject <PFSubclassing>

- (id)calculateStreak;

@end
```

Then, make sure you override the `parseClassName` to return the Parse class name:

```
@implementation Habit

- (NSString *)parseClassName
{
    return @"Habit";
}

@end
```

You also have to register your subclass, which should be done in `+[Habit load]`:

```
@implementation Habit

- (void)load
{
    [self registerSubclass];
}

- (NSString *)parseClassName
{
    return @"Habit";
}

@end
```

Then you can instantiate the class the way you would any other Parse class, using `+[object]` or the like:

```
Habit *habit = [Habit object];
```

Comment: Thanks for you response! I got that far, what I am having trouble with is instantiating with data from the cloud. So after fetching it with a `query`, I have an `array` of `PFObject`s. How would I (re)? instantiate the objects as `Habit` type?

Comment: @espitia If you've registered the Habit type, and they are "Habit" objects, all you should have to do is cast them. `Habit *habit = (Habit *)myPFObject;`